# Adding a phone frame mockup to an embedded video

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, youtube

I hope you can help. I'm basically looking for a way to intigrate some videos into my Wordpress blog and don't know where to start. The videos were shot vertically for Instagram, and I want to show them vertically in a phone frame. [hand holding phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OmZv6.jpg)

I tried uploading a five second video of me laughing about some dogs sitting in the drivers seat of a parked car but it was 15MB and wouldn't even play, so I reckon my best bet would be using unlisted Youtube videos and embedding them. This is the video, it really tickled me. [dogs in scotland pretending to drive car, very important](https://mylegshurt.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2023/01/VID_20220614_124726.mp4)

Basically what I'm asking is whether there's a way to add a border or a frame to a vertical video, and would anybody be able to point me in the right direction for any relevent code if so?

Cheers in advance :)

I've tried adding a frame using Final Cut and Photoshop, but I have hundreds of short ridiculous videos and was hoping there would be a way I could automatically add a frame using code each time I embed a Youtube video. I will be resuming my walk around the coast of Britain soon and won't have access to my laptop for the next year so if there was some code I could copy and paste each time that would be ideal.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an structure like this one:

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <img src="./assest/phone-frame.png" />
    <video scr="./assets/video.mp4" />
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    height: 700px;
}
.wrapper img {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
}
.wrapper video {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

You just need to adjust the position of the img and video to make them match using the top and left properties (or right and bottom, whichever you fancy)